# Can prepositions and verbs have an indirect object(s) or is the object of a verb(s) or preposition(s) always direct?

Tags: objects, direct-objects, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects

This is something I have always wondered, but I have been struggling with the subject-object thing for too long a time now, I can still very much in English learner.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "direct objects" and "indirect objects"? If so, what did those searches tell you?